# std::make_shared leads to undefined behavior, but new works

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr

Consider the following example class:

```
class Foo {

public:
    void* const arr_;

    Foo() = delete;

    Foo(const size_t size, bool high_precision) :
        arr_(Initialize(size, high_precision)) {};

    template <typename T>
    T* GetDataPointer() {
        return (T* const)arr_;
    }
private:
    static void* Initialize(const size_t size, bool high_prec) {
        if (high_prec) {
            return new double[size];
        }
        else {
            return new float[size];
        }
    }

};
```

When I created a shared pointer to a Foo object using `std::make_shared`, I often find the array data I initialize displays undefined behavior/becomes corrupted. For example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sp_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo(3,false));
    auto foo_data = sp_foo->GetDataPointer<float>();
    foo_data[0] = 1.1;
    foo_data[1] = 2.2;
    foo_data[2] = 3.3;
    std::cout << "First Value: " << 
        sp_foo->GetDataPointer<float>()[0]; // Sometimes this is 1.1, sometimes it is meaningless.
```

However, when I initialize the shared pointer using `new`, this problem seems to go away.

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sp_foo (new Foo(3,false));
    auto foo_data = sp_foo->GetDataPointer<float>();
    foo_data[0] = 1.1;
    foo_data[1] = 2.2;
    foo_data[2] = 3.3;
    std::cout << "First Value: " << 
        sp_foo->GetDataPointer<float>()[0]; // Correctly prints 1.1
```

Any thoughts as to what is happening? Small side note: I am constrained to not template the `Foo` class and to indeed have a `void* const` to the onboard data array.

Comment: Looks like you are using copy constructor with `make_shared`, which is autogenerated by the compiler, hence wrong, because your class is using `new[]`; Try `std::make_shared<Foo>(3, false);` instead

Comment: You should probably also fix or delete the copy constructor.

Comment: To be explicit - your class `Foo` doesn't consider [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) - it needs a destructor, and therefore needs other member functions as well.   And `std::make_shared` already calls a constructor, so `std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo(3,false))` unnecessarily calls _two_ Foo constructors.

Comment: I'm guessing what you've shown us isn't a [mre]

Comment: Re: "displays undefined behavior" -- undefined behavior isn't a thing that happens; it's a description of your program. Under some circumstances the language definition doesn't tell you what the behavior of a program should be. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: There more mistakes in this code (memory leak since there is no deallocation by smart pointer or destructor). What is desired functionality (since current code is a bit weird).

Comment: O, I didn't notice that the destructor of your class is missing, I just assumed it's there and it is deleting the memory. Is it intentional, or you just forgot to copy-paste your full class body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `make_shared` is using a copy constructor for your `Foo` class, which you haven't defined. Thus, the default (compiler-generated) copy will be used, and the destructor will be called to delete the temporary. As your class doesn't properly implement the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), this (potentially) causes undefined behaviour.

The copy constructor is being used because the argument list in your call to `std::make_shared` is `Foo(3, false)` – a `Foo` object, so the call fits *only* the first overload listed on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). (Note that there is nothing resembling a `std::make_shared<T>(const T& src)` overload.) From that page, we see:

> 1. Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::shared_ptr
>    using args as the parameter list for the constructor of T.

So, with your "args" of `Foo(3, false)`, that `make_shared` actually calls the following constructor for the object to wrap:

```cpp
Foo(Foo(3, false))
```

For correct behaviour, just pass the `3` and `false` as arguments to `make_shared`:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sp_foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(3, false);
```

You can *demonstrate* the error in your original code by adding a destructor to the `Foo` class that logs some output, like: `~Foo() { std::cout << "Destroying...\n"; }`. You will see that output after execution of the call to `make_shared`.

You can *prevent* this accidental error/oversight by deleting the `Foo` copy constructor: `Foo(const Foo& f) = delete;`. This will generate a compiler error along the following lines:

> error : call to deleted constructor of 'Foo'

---

However, in your second case, you use a [`std::shared_ptr` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) (the third form shown on the linked page). This has no problem, because that constructor 'just' wraps the given pointer into the managed object, and no copying or destruction is needed.

Comment: As the class doesn't have a destructor `arr_` isn't deleted so there isn't any undefined behaviour from the copied object

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah - I added "(potentially)" to the undefined behaviour part. But a destructor or a copy c'tor would be very difficult, anyway: `delete [] p;` on a `void*` is UB according to clang: *warning : cannot delete expression with pointer-to-'void' type 'void *' [-Wdelete-incomplete]*. And copying data from a `void*`, not knowing its size or underlying type will be *very* tricky.